# Fragment back even

Tags: android, xamarin

i use fragment where is list view and on item click i changed this fragment to details.
I want to add custom back button inside details view..

I wrote this event

```
private void _Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fragmentTransaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            var _fragment = new ForecastRegionListFragment();         
            fragmentTransaction.Attach(_fragment).Commit();
            fragmentTransaction.Show(_fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.Remove(this);

            MyApplication._Back.Click -= _Back_Click;
            MyApplication._Back.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
```

but i think that it is not good way to do back. can u advice me better version ?

Comment: You can just call finish(); in the backbutton code.

Comment: i don't want to finith application, i want to go back previous fragment

Comment: @NinoSvanidze `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032956/action-bar-back-button-not-working` check out that answer in that link.In fragment you have to use intent to pass to the activity.And then set the onBackPressed() Code in Activity.Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this will help, just programmatically call the back button and attach it to the touch button

[Android: Proper Way to use onBackPressed() with Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413700/android-proper-way-to-use-onbackpressed)

cheers

Comment: I want back from fragment and not from activity.

Comment: addToBackStack(null) should be added when you call the new fragments or activity, this adds it to the stack which is navigated when using back button functionality