# Android Action Bar navigation up button not working on devices

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, navigationbar

Action Bar up navigation button [image: Action Bar Back Button]  works fine in emulator but does not work in device can any one help me out

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/AGENCYB.TTF");

    Button btnWeatherDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeather);
    Button btnMovieDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMovies);
    Button btnHoroscopeDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHoroscope);

    btnWeatherDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WeatherActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    btnMovieDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);             
        }
    });

    btnHoroscopeDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HoroscopeActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);     
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    SharedPreferences settingsPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor settingsEditor= settingsPreferences.edit();
    settingsEditor.putBoolean(MovieActivity.MOVIEUPDATED, false);
    settingsEditor.putBoolean(HoroscopeActivity.HOROSCOPEAVAILABLE, false);
    settingsEditor.commit();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

WeatherActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scrollmain);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    settingsPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SavedString = settingsPreferences.getString(JSONWEATHERSTRING, "Not Found");

    new JSONParse().execute(WeatherUrl);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    WeatherActivity.this.finish();
}
```

MovieActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    settingsPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

    MovieJsonString = settingsPreferences.getString(JSONMOVIESTRING, "Not Found");
    isMovieUpdated = settingsPreferences.getBoolean(MOVIEUPDATED, false);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_list_view);        
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    movieList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    list = getListView();
    // Calling async task to get json
    if(!isMovieUpdated)
        new GetMovieDetails().execute();
    else
        GetMoviePreferences();

}

public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    MovieActivity.this.finish();
}
```

HoroscopeActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.horoscope);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    settingsPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

    isHoroAvailable = settingsPreferences.getBoolean(HOROSCOPEAVAILABLE,false);

    if(!isHoroAvailable)
        new XMLParse().execute();
    else
        GetHoroscopeFromPreference();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    HoroscopeActivity.this.finish();
}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.datumdata.weather"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_hosurdata"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MovieActivity"
            android:label="Movie Details"
            android:parentActivityName="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActvity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="in.datumdata.hosurdata.WeatherActivity"
            android:label="Weather Details"
            android:parentActivityName="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActvity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="in.datumdata.hosurdata.SingleContactActivity"
            android:label="Movie Details"
            android:parentActivityName="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MovieActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="in.datumdata.hosurdata.HoroscopeActivity"
            android:label="Horoscope Details"
            android:parentActivityName="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActvity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="in.datumdata.hosurdata.SingleHoroscopeActivity"
            android:label="Horoscope Details"
            android:parentActivityName="in.datumdata.hosurdata.HoroscopeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In all the above activities the navigation button [image: Action Bar Back Button] works fine in emulator but on device it does not work and when i press the back button on the device [image] the application goes invisible i mean to say its running in the background. This thing happens on all activities on whatever activity i press back button the same thing happens

help me out. thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you do this:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Try doing this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use a meta data tags for Up button to work on older APIs:

```
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MainActivity" />
```

EDIT:

You already have the parentActivityName, so add only the meta tag to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file's  tags. Like so:

```
    <activity
        android:name="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MovieActivity"
        android:label="Movie Details"
        android:parentActivityName="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActvity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActvity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: should i add this in each and every activity

Comment: To all activities that should have the **Up button**. Also change the activity names so they match the ones that should be called.

Comment: sorry din get u change activity name?

Comment: When you copy meta-data, change the `in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActvity` to your activity. What's not to understand?

Comment: you mean to say instead of using in.datumdata.hosurdata.MainActvity just MainActivity is enough

Comment: I mean for different Activity you will use different meta-data. Like for Horscope Details, you will use `in.datumdata.hosurdata.HoroscopeActivity`, while for Movie Details you will use `in.datumdata.hosurdata.MovieActivity`.

Answer (score 5):

If your activity gets called from multiple activities and specifying parent activity doesn't fit your use case, then you can fix it by adding this:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  (in onCreate)


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with support action bar and if you're using support actionbar then you've to add this line in your code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And in the manifest you need to add

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
```

So the activity declaration in manifest will look like:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MyActivity"
    android:label="My Activity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
</activity>
```

You can't add `android:parentActivityName="com.example.ParentActivity"` in the activity declaration in manifest if you're using API level less than 16.