# Android: Switching between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one `Main Activity` that is used as Menu from which a user can go to different Fragments. As switching from one activity to another we do use the Intent for this purpose. And in the same manner we use the `onBackPressed()` method to go back to the previous Activity. Now my scenario is First I am going from `MainActivity` (Activity class) to a class that I am extending from Fragment and after that I am going to another fragment (the child fragment of the second). Now I want to go back from that 2nd fragment to the previous fragment but I don't able to achieve although I have tried many things. Just for test I did this

```
Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class) ; 
startActivity(in);
getActivity().finish();
```

and this brings me to the main Activity. But I want to go back to the previous Fragment. I have tried `OnKeyDown` but for fragment it shows me errors that `onkeydown` is undefine for type `Fragments`. Please give me a simple example that demonstrate the back pressed from one activity to another.
I have used this code to go to second Fragment and it brings me well to second fragment but when I press the Back key it shows me a white blank screen, here is my code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("KEY", dealItem);

                Fragment fragment = new DealCompleteDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                actionBar = MainActivity.myCustomActionBar;
                actionBar.hide();
```

**EDITED:**

```
public class DealsFragment extends Fragment {
    DatabaseService dbService;
    Services service;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    FragmentDealAdapter lazyadapter;
    RefreshableListView mPullRefreshListView;
    MyArrayList<DealItemDetail> dealDetailItem = new MyArrayList<DealItemDetail>();

    public DealsFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deals, container,
                false);

        ListView shopList = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_deal_listview);

        dbService = DatabaseService.getInstance(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());
        service = new Services(getActivity());
lazyadapter = new FragmentDealAdapter(getActivity(), dealDetailItem,
                (dealDetailItem.size() > limit) ? limit : dealDetailItem.size());
        shopList.setAdapter(lazyadapter);

        shopList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DealItemDetail dealItem = dealDetailItem.get(position - 1);

                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("KEY", dealItem);

                    Fragment fragment = new DealCompleteDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager();
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    actionBar = MainActivity.myCustomActionBar;
                    actionBar.hide();
                }
            }
        });

return rootView;
}
```

**Activity Oncrate:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerListLeft = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu_left);
        mDrawerListRight = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu_right);

        navDrawerItemsLeft = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
        navDrawerItemsRight = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // Left Drawer Items

        navDrawerItemsLeft.add(new NavDrawerItem(Constants.SHOP_SCREEN_TITLE, false, false, false));
        navDrawerItemsLeft.add(new NavDrawerItem(Constants.DEALS_SCREEN_TITLE, false, false, false));


mDrawerListLeft.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuLeftClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapterLeftDrawer = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItemsLeft);
        mDrawerListLeft.setAdapter(adapterLeftDrawer);


LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        imgLeftMenu  = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imgLeftMenu);
actionBarTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_action_bar);



getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#93b636")));

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);

        myCustomActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);

        ((View)homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        imgLeftMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListLeft)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerListLeft);
                } else {
                    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListRight)){
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerListRight);
                    }
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerListLeft);
                }
            }
        });

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            //          LeftMenuClickListner(0);
        }


private void LeftMenuClickListner(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ShopsNew();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new DealsNew();
            break;
default:
            break;
        }

if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerListLeft.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerListLeft.setSelection(position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerListLeft);
        }}
```

Comment: Check that answer posted in that link.`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032956/action-bar-back-button-not-working`

Comment: you're probably not using `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(new WhateverFragment(), R.id.main_fragment_container).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: @Zhuinden I am using this to go to next Fragment and now i am in second Fragment and when I press back button it only show me an empty screen.

Comment: are you sure you had `.addToBackStack(null)` ? and that you added the first fragment in the same manner as `if(savedInstanceState == null) { getSFM().bT().add(new FirstFragment(), R.id.main_fragment_container).aTBS(null).commit(); }`?

Comment: so how do you create the FIRST fragment?

Comment: I just simple extend it from Fragment and inflate a view for it and there are some click listeners and nothing else there.

Comment: ....post your entire Activity `onCreate(..)` code.

Comment: @Zhuinden see the code above now.

Comment: this is the fragment, we need the Activity because that's where the problem is, specifically Activity onCreate()

Comment: this is the first fragment from which i go to second one but any how i am gonna post the activity code too

Comment: @Zhuinden See now the last updateed code

Comment: Look at that, `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();` is missing .addToBackStack(null); please note that I think if the screen gets rotated it automatically tries creating the zero index Fragment, in which case you would need to call `if(savedInstanceState != null) { onBackPressed(); }`

Comment: @Zhuinden Did what you said but the problem remain unsolved.

Comment: wait, you added .addToBackStack(null) to that line and it is still not working? o.o?

Comment: Yes see the line FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
     .addToBackStack(null).commit();