# AppCompatPreferenceActivity with addPreferencesFromResource up not working

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am using AppCompatPreferenceActivity so that I can add the Toolbar at the top of the screen. Problem is that the back button on the toolbar is not working. 
Since I am not using my own layout I have no access to the Toolbar in order to set setNavigationOnClickListener as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410538/appcompatpreferenceactivity-up-button-not-working)

This is my Activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.preferences);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferencesMain()).commit();
}

/**
 * This fragment contains a second-level set of preference that you
 * can get to by tapping an item in the first preferences fragment.
 */
public static class PreferencesMain extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


        ((Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_account_about))).setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "About clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        ((Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_account_logout))).setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                new UserSignOutRequest(getActivity(),
                    new ServerSuccessListener<CreateUserEntity>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccessResponse(String response, CreateUserEntity jsonResponse) {
                            UserControl.signOut(getActivity());
                            Utilities.startSignInActivity(getActivity());
                        }

                    },
                    new ServerErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(ServerRequestError serverRequestError) {

                        }
                        }
                ).execute(getActivity());
                return true;
            }
        });

        ((Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_account_deleteAccount))).setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Delete Account clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

@Override
protected boolean isValidFragment (String fragmentName) {
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();   // If on first fragment then exit then activity
}
```

}

and this is my XML file:

```
    <!-- This PreferenceScreen tag sends the user to a new fragment of
         preferences.  If running in a large screen, they can be embedded
         inside of the overall preferences UI. -->
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushTitle"
        android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushSummary"
        android:background="@android:color/black">


            <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushHeader">

                <CheckBoxPreference
                    android:key="checkbox_preference"
                    android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Title"
                    android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Summary" />
            </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="@string/settings_notifications_manageEmailTitle"
        android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_manageEmailSummary"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
            <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="@string/settings_notifications_manageEmailHeader">

                <CheckBoxPreference
                    android:key="checkbox_preference"
                    android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Title"
                    android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Summary" />
            </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="@string/settings_notifications_manageSMSTitle"
        android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_manageSMSSummary"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/settings_notifications_manageSMSHeader">

            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="checkbox_preference"
                android:title="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Title"
                android:summary="@string/settings_notifications_managePushEntry1Summary" />
        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>


</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/settings_moneyAndCredits"
    android:layout="@layout/preference_category">

    <!-- The key value is unused but is required so that findPreference can work -->
    <customviews.IconPreference android:title="@string/settings_moneyAndCredits_defaultPaymentMethod"
        android:key="@string/settings_moneyAndCredits_defaultPaymentMethod"
        app:preferenceIcon="@drawable/settings_payment_method"/>
    <customviews.IconPreference android:title="@string/settings_moneyAndCredits_incomingPaymentAccounts"
        android:key="@string/settings_moneyAndCredits_incomingPaymentAccounts"
        app:preferenceIcon="@drawable/settings_manage_incomings"/>


</PreferenceCategory>


<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/settings_account"
    android:layout="@layout/preference_category">
    <!-- The key value is unused but is required so that findPreference can work -->
    <customviews.IconPreference android:title="@string/settings_account_about"
        android:key="@string/settings_account_about"
        app:preferenceIcon="@drawable/settings_about"/>
    <customviews.IconPreference android:title="@string/settings_account_logout"
        android:key="@string/settings_account_logout"
        app:preferenceIcon="@drawable/settings_logout"/>
    <customviews.IconPreference  android:title="@string/settings_account_deleteAccount"
        android:key="@string/settings_account_deleteAccount"
        app:preferenceIcon="@drawable/settings_delete_user"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

I am using two levels of PreferenceScreen because I need to mix different types and any other way gave me overlayed screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have access to `ActionBar` in both the cases i.e. default layout and custom layout (as far as `getSupportActionBar()` is returning you the `ActionBar`). And you already have enabled back button by adding `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` you can just override `onOptionsItemSelected` in your `Activity` like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // Write your code here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Or if you want to add this method in `Fragment` just add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in Fragment's `onCreate` method and override `onOptionsItemSelected` in your `Fragment`.
I think it is what you want. Isn't that?